# Adding Firebase data to Tableview using Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin, tableview

I am new to iOS development using Xamarin. I am trying to load data from my realtime firebase database into a table view. Currently my code is

```
public async override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        TestButton.TouchUpInside += TestButton_TouchUpInside;

        //List<string> names = new List<string>
        //{
        //    "Line 1","Line 2"
        //};
        //tbl_tran.Source = new TranTableViewSource(names);

        List<Tran> all = await FirebaseHandle.getInstance().GetAllTrans();
        tbl_tran.Source = new TranTableViewSource(new List<string>
        {
            all[0].Descript.ToString()
        });
        TestLabel.Text = all[0].Descript.ToString();
    }
```

The TestLabel fills with the proper value but the table does not, so I know my firebase section is functioning properly. Additionally, If I uncomment the string list, my table view will fill with line 1 and line 2. For reference I have attached my view source class and getAllTrans() method. I'm unsure if there's a listener or something I need. Any info on getting my firebase data into the table view would be appreciated.

```
public class TranTableViewSource : UITableViewSource
{

    List<String> names;

    public TranTableViewSource(List<string> names)
    {
        this.names = names;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, "");
        cell.TextLabel.Text = names[indexPath.Row];

        return cell;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return names.Count;
    }

}
```

And

```
public async Task<List<Tran>> GetAllTrans()
    {
        return (await firebase
          .Child("Tran")
          .OnceAsync<Tran>()).Select(item => new Tran
          {
              Descript = item.Object.Descript,
              Amount = item.Object.Amount,
              IsMatt = item.Object.IsMatt,
              Date = item.Object.Date
          }).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: have you checked that `names` is being properly passed into `TranTableViewSource`?

Comment: Yes, If I uncomment the lines in "viewDidLoad()" the basic string list passes fine and is added to the table view

Comment: That's not what I'm asking.  I want to know if the "real" data is getting passed correctly.  And why don't you just pass `all` instead of extracting just a list of string?

Comment: how would I check that?

Comment: use the debugger.  Or just add  `Console.Writeline(this.names[0]);` in the constructor

Comment: Yes, when I write to the console in constructor of  TranTableViewSource, the data outputs correctly

Comment: That's weird.  Not sure what to suggest without seeing the code in action.

Comment: Is there some listener I need to implement? I notice when my label loads, It takes a second to change from the default value to the one from firebase. I'm wondering if it's trying to built the tableview before names is initialized

Comment: I don't think that's the issue.  What happens if you do `cell.TextLabel.Text = "blah";`?

Comment: I also get a blank table, unless again I pass in the List of Strings (line 1, line 2)

Comment: the only reason I can think that would happen is if you were passing in null data.  But you've said that you're testing for that.  if you add a `Console.Writeline` to `RowsInSection` does it return the correct value?  I'd also modify your TableSource to work with a `List<Tran>` and avoid the step of selecting just the string values

Comment: Yeah that's the plan, I switched it to strings to be bug. I figured it out, I can simply call reload table and it gets the job done.